# What is wrong with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I wrote some simple javascript code, but it does not return the expected result.

```
var arr = new Array();

var firstobj = {
   cta: 0,
   ccc: 0,
   crc: 0
}
for (var ta = 1; ta <= 10; ta++) {
    arr[ta] = firstobj;
}

arr[6].cta = 1;
console.log(arr);
```

I only change cta value of 6th element, but it changes for all elements.

Expected:

```
[{cta:0, ccc:0, crc:0}, ..., {cta:1, ccc:0, crc:0}, {cta:0, ccc:0, crc:0}, ...]
//                                ^ 6th element
```

Actual:

```
[{cta:1, ccc:0, crc:0, ...] // All have 1
```

Comment: What is the "expected result"? The current result is expected for sure.

Comment: arrays are zero based

Comment: Only the 6th element's cta value must be 1, but all elements cta values change. Clear?

Comment: You don't clone the object - so all the array elements refer to the same and the only object.

Comment: You're basically assigning each element in the array a reference to the original object. You're not creating a new object in memory for each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects in Javascript are assigned by pointer (well technically JS doesn't have pointers, but it works like a pointer does in other languages).  So, you have filled your array so that every element contains a pointer-like reference to the exact same object.  Thus, when you change that object, you see the change everywhere because there's only one object and you changed it.

If you want to initialize an array with separate objects, you have to create a new object or clone an existing object and assign that separate object into each element of your array.

For example, you could do that like this:

```js
var myArray = [];
var obj;
// Also, arrays start from 0, not from 1.
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // create a new object for each item in the array
  obj = {cta:0, ccc:0, crc:0};
  myArray[i] = obj;
} 

myArray[6].cta = 1;
document.write(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Comment: "Objects in Javascript are assigned by pointer." --- there are no pointers in JS though.

Comment: @zerkms - it works just like a pointer and the behavior it has it much more like a pointer than anything else because it is not a true reference.  I've found that describing it as a pointer seems to work the best for newbies in this regard.

Comment: There is a name for it "call by sharing". But the "assigned by pointer" is strictly wrong.

Comment: @zerkms - I've edited that part of the answer a bit.  It's not a true reference.  It's not a true value.  It actually works just like a pointer.  I've heard people describe it as assigned by value and the value is a reference, but that particularly doesn't help any newbie understand how it actually works regardless of how technically accurate it is.  "call by sharing" doesn't seem to make sense here.

Comment: Okay. But it's doubtful for me that someone that understands pointers cannot understand "call by sharing".

Comment: @zerkms - There's no "call" here at all though - this is an assignment operation.  So "call by sharing" doesn't work here.  Perhaps you're thinking of passing an object as a function argument.  That isn't what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

> Only the 6th element's cta value must be 1, but all elements cta
>   values change.

all the elements in your array(apart from element at zero index , which would be `undefined` in your case)  are referring to the same object so if you change property in one element it is refelected across all elements

Answer (score 1):

you assigned the same object reference to all values in the array

make it (use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create))

```
for (var ta = 1; ta <=  10; ta++) 
{
    arr [ta] = Object.create( firstobj );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you save the same `firstobj` to your array it saved by reference so when you changing one of the values it changes all of them, my suggestion is to create a new object for each element in your array.

```js
var arr = new Array();

for (var ta = 1; ta <=  10; ta++) {
  arr [ta] = { cta:0,
               ccc:0,
               crc:0
            };
}

arr[6].cta=1;
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks. We decided to use your solution like this: 

for (var ta = 1; ta <=  10; ta++) {
var firstobj = {
   cta: 0,
   ccc: 0,
   crc: 0
}
  arr [ta] =firstobj;
}

Answer (score 0):

Each element in array is referring to same object.
So when you change object value it is reflected in all elements.